# How to fetch records from the last X days with minimal number of records using stored procedure or LINQ?

Tags: sql, .net, linq, stored-procedures

I have the following table

```
ID    Date
---------------------------
1     2017-07-13 12:18:07.293
2     2017-07-16 06:36:02.340
3     2017-03-17 06:36:02.340
4     2017-04-18 06:36:02.340
5     2017-02-12 06:36:02.340
6     2018-07-03 06:36:02.340
7     2018-07-04 06:36:02.340
```

I have X which stands for number of days, and Y as minimum number of records.

I need to fetch all the records from the last X days and in case the number of records which return is less than Y, return the Y last records.

For example, fetch records from the last 7 days (x=7), while min number of records is 3, I expect to get:

```
5   2017-02-12 06:36:02.340
6   2018-07-03 06:36:02.340
7   2018-07-04 06:36:02.340
```

I wrote the following code, but i'm looking to improve it:

```
DateTime minDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-numOfDays);
var jobs = myList.Where(x => x.CreatedOnUtc > minDate);
if (jobs.Count() >= minItems)
    return jobs;

int maxId = myList.Max(x => x.Id);
return myList.Where(x => x.Id > maxId - minItems);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. And which dbms ate you using?

Comment: @jarlh , thanks, i've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

This be my first answer on StackOverflow so be nice?  :-)

I an pro-SQL here at work so here's my stab at this..

```
DECLARE @X INT -- Number of days
DECLARE @Y INT -- Minimum number of records

SET @X = 7
SET @Y = 3

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Days') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Days

CREATE TABLE #Days
    (
    RowID INT IDENTITY,
    ID INT,
    [Date] DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO #Days (ID,[Date]) VALUES (1,'2017-07-13 12:18:07.293')
INSERT INTO #Days (ID,[Date]) VALUES (2,'2017-07-16 06:36:02.340')
INSERT INTO #Days (ID,[Date]) VALUES (3,'2017-03-17 06:36:02.340')
INSERT INTO #Days (ID,[Date]) VALUES (4,'2017-04-18 06:36:02.340')
INSERT INTO #Days (ID,[Date]) VALUES (5,'2017-02-12 06:36:02.340')
INSERT INTO #Days (ID,[Date]) VALUES (6,'2018-07-03 06:36:02.340')
INSERT INTO #Days (ID,[Date]) VALUES (7,'2018-07-04 06:36:02.340')

IF  (
    SELECT  COUNT(1)
    FROM    #Days
    WHERE   CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) >= DATEADD("DD",-1*@x,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
    ) <= @Y
BEGIN

    SELECT  TOP (@Y) *
    FROM    #Days

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT   *
    FROM    #Days
    WHERE   CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) >= DATEADD("DD",-1*@x,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))

END
```